# Rails not saving entry after clicking submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My app worked perfectly fine before installing the Devise gem. After installing Devise, when I click submit on the form it reloads the same page and doesn't save the entry into the table. It should redirect to the 'ask' page where it asks the user if there are more entries. I have tried multiple solutions from this site but none of them seem to work so I wanted to post this question to get it to work and an understanding of what is going on. The naming might get confusing. My first model is Members, with fields input, gifttext, spouse, and spousegift. After installing Devise I put a users model with the fields email and encrypted_password.

My members_controller.rb:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController

include MembersHelper
def new
  @member = Member.new
end  
def index
    @members = Member.all
end
def destroy 
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    @members = Member.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to members_path
end
def create
   @member = Member.new(member_params)
if @member.save
  redirect_to :action => 'ask'
else
  render :action => 'new'
end
end
def ask
end
def show
end
def update
    @article = Member.find(params[:id])

    if @member.update(member_params)
        redirect_to @member
    else
        render 'edit'
        end
    end
def results
    @matches = prints
end
def member_params
      params.require(:member).permit(:input, :gifttext, :spouse, :spousegift)
end

end
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

My member.rb:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

My _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: @member, local: true ) do |f| %>
<p>Who is the participant?</p>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :person %>
    <%= f.text_field :input %>
</div>
<p>What gifts would they like?</p>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :gifts %>
  <%= f.text_field :gifttext %>
</div>
<p>Who, if anyone, is their spouse? If they don't have one you can leave this field blank</p>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :spouse %>
  <%= f.text_field :spouse %>
</div>
<p>What gifts would they like? If there is no spouse then you can leave this field blank.</p>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :gifts %>
  <%= f.text_field :spousegift %>
</div>
  <div class="action">
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</div>
  <%= link_to 'Matches', members_results_path(@member) %>
<% end %>
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'members/new'
  get 'members/results'
  get 'members/index'
  get 'names/new'
  get 'names/results'
  get 'names/index'
  root 'members#new'
  post 'members/new'
  get 'members/ask'
  resources :members
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

My migration for the users model:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

My Members migration:

```
class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      t.string :input
      t.string :gifttext
      t.string :spouse
      t.string :spousegift

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Probably `@member` record is invalid. In `create` method, use `save!` instead of `save`. It will raise an exception (if the record is invalid) that might help (please add it to your question)

Comment: `@article = Member.find(params[:id])` should be `@member = Member.find(params[:id])` instead

Comment: It seems to me as you want to authorize member instead of user (it is an instance of it but the name of the class is different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MembersController#update method uses a `@article` instance variable. You probably meant `@member`:

```
def update
  @member = Member.find(params[:id])

  if @member.update(member_params)
    redirect_to @member
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Your create action doesn't look quite right either you need to set the user and redirect correctly:

```
def create
  @member = Member.new(member_params)
  @member.user = current_user
  if @member.save
    redirect_to ask_member_path(@member)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= @member.errors.inspect %>
```

Comment: I made these changes but unfortunately, it still does not save the data. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You need to see the ```@member.errors``` in the form, so you can see why it is not being saved. My wildest guess is, that since it belongs to a user you need to assign the current_user. I made the change in my comment above.

Comment: I'm getting this on the form page after putting <%= @member.errors.inspect %>: #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000000c6ebcf0 @base=#<Member id: nil, input: nil, gifttext: nil, spouse: nil, spousegift: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:person=>[], :input=>[], :gifts=>[], :gifttext=>[], :spouse=>[], :spousegift=>[]}, @details={}>. And when I make the changes to the create action I get this error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in MembersController#create 
can't write unknown attribute `user_id`

Comment: what does your members table look like? It should have a user_id column when you are using ```belongs_to :user```

Comment: This may actually be the case. I edited the question to show when I added the Members migration for when I created the table so you can see the columns. How would I go about adding a user_id column after the table is already created? Hope this fixes it.

Comment: You create a migration as described in the migrations section of the ruby on rails guides